# Pylance thinks that an index into an H5 file does not create a group

Tags: type-hinting, h5py, pylance

The following minimal example works fine:

```py
import h5py

f = h5py.File("mytestfile.hdf5", "w")
f.create_group("hello") # Pylance error here
f["hello"].create_dataset("hello", data=1)

g = f.create_group("bye")
g.create_dataset("bye", data=2)

f.close()
```

However, on the indicated, line, Pylance throws an error, saying `Cannot access member "create_dataset" for type "Dataset" Member "create_dataset" is unknown` (And the same error again on the same line for "Datatype" instead of "Dataset".) Note that this error does not occur on the later line that runs the same `create_dataset` function.

Even adding an `assert isinstance(f["hello"], h5py.Group)` before the erroring line does not solve the issue.

Why does Pylance think that `f["hello"]` is a `Datatype` or `Dataset` and not a `Group`?

I've also looked at [the codebase](https://github.com/h5py/h5py) to see if I can find where the indexing magic method happens and can't easily find it to see if it's typed correctly and/or fix it.

How can I get Pylance to understand that `f["hello"]` is a group that can create a dataset?

Answer (score 0):

After seeing that Pylance thinks that `k` in `k = f["hello"]` is of type `Group | Dataset | Datatype`, I realized what is going on.

First of all, clearly Pylance *does* think that `f["hello"]` can be a Group, it just also thinks that it could be a Dataset or Datatype and the `create_dataset` method doesn't exist for those types, so it rightly throws an error.

The assertion method of fixing it that I tried really should work (**I'd appreciate a comment explaining why this is hard to do / isn't the default behavior in static type checking**), but the static type checking is not that advanced yet.

Rather, if you do `k = f["hello"]`, and then follow that up with the assertion `assert isinstance(k, h5py.Group)`, and *then* do `k.create_dataset("hello", data=1)`, no error will by thrown by Pylance.

You can also solve it with a cast, like `k = cast(h5py.Group, f["hello"])`, and then, again, no error is thrown by the `create_dataset`.